# ionic2 - component into other page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a component `ProcessStep` with its own `ts` and `html` file.:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-process-step',
  templateUrl: 'process-step.html'
})
export class ProcessStep {
totalsteps:number;
steparray:Array<boolean>;
currentstep = 1;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello ProcessStep Page');
  }
  populateStep(n:number){
    for(var i =1; i<=n ; i++){
      this.steparray.push(false);
    }
  }

}
```

`ProcessStep` is used in many pages with different `step` value. When I call `populateStep()` from other page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProcessStep } from '../process-step/process-step';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class Login {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public modalCtrl:ModalController,
              public loadingCtrl:LoadingController,
              private processstep:ProcessStep
              ) {
                processstep.populateStep(5);///<-- give error
              }
```

I got an error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./Login class Login_Host - inline template:0:0
>   caused by: No provider for ProcessStep!

How can I prepare the provider for `ProcessStep`?

Comment: I get new error after adding to `@NgModule.providers`: >No provider for NavController!

Comment: How to use shared service? is that the same with provider? `ProcessStep` is a view component with minor customisation. I follow @huiting 's answer and it works. However, for some reason `ngFor` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ProcessStep` is a component used by other components, you should get a reference to it with `@ViewChild`

```
import { ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

class Login implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ProcessStep) step: ProcessStep;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    step.populateStep(5);
  }
}
```